# Iterating thru JS array, sorting prices?

Tags: javascript, sorting, price

Okay so I'm trying to sort items on my webpage, I use getElementsByClassName and it saves it as a nodelist or array I'm not sure, but it says h2 price, h2 price, h2 price when I console.log.  I just want the item prices so I can sort them  When I view the innerHTML it has the item price I want, how do I get that instead of 'h2 price' so I can remove the $ and then sort by highest or lowest price first?

Here's some of my HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="product-image-wrapper">
<div class="single-products">
  <div class="productinfo text-center">
    <img src="images\site_images\bag3.jpg" alt="" height="249" />
    <h2 class="price">$881.10</h2>
    <h5>Authentic New Gucci ($1690) Micro-GG "Vernice" Crossbody w/Strap #309617, NWT</h5>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to Cart</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="product-image-wrapper">
      <div class="single-products">
        <div class="productinfo text-center">
          <img src="images\site_images\bag4.jpg" alt="" height="249" />
          <h2 class="price">$569.05</h2>
          <h5>AUTHENTIC NWT ($819) Gucci GG Large Brown Denim Tassell Tote #336660, w/Gft Rcpt</h5>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to Cart</a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <div class="product-image-wrapper">
            <div class="single-products">
              <div class="productinfo text-center">
                <img src="images\site_images\bag5.jpg" alt="" height="249" />
                <h2 class="price">$559.00</h2>
                <h5>Authentic Gucci GG Micro-Guccissima Leather Tote #309613 w/Gft Rcpt,NWT</h5>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to Cart</a>
              </div>
              <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
              <p id="demo"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('price');
    var prices = [];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `Array.prototype.slice()` , `Array.prototype.map()` to convert `HTMLCollection` to `Array` , `Number()` , `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/\$/` , `Array.prototype.sort()`

```
function myFunction() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("price"))
  .map(function(el) {return Number(el.innerHTML.replace(/\$/, ""))})
  .sort();
}
```